# Remove spaces between bars in barplot 2 factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have code following:

```
df=data.frame(time=as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5,each=10)),roi=rep(1:10,10),area=runif(1‌​00, 5.0, 7.5)) 

df$time <- factor(df$time, levels=rev(levels(df$time)))

ggplot(data=df, aes(y=factor(roi), x=time, fill = area)) + theme_minimal() + coord_flip() + geom_tile(colour = "white", width = 0.9, height = 0.5) + scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

How can I remove the spaces between bars of 10 rois (I mean the spaces between rois) and make 10 bars of 10 rois stay continuously for each value of time. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of the `height` and `width` arguments to `geom_tile`, use `coord_fixed(ratio=r)` to control the aspect ratio of
  the tiles (where `r` is the ratio). I've used r=0.5 in the example below.
- Switch the `x` and `y` columns so that you get `roi` on the x-axis without needing `coord_flip()` (you can't use both `coord_flip()` and `coord_fixed()` at the same time).
- Set `colour=NA` so that there won't be a space between each tile within a given row.
- Set `height=0.9` to create a space between each row of tiles.

  ```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(roi), y=time, fill = area)) + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    coord_fixed(ratio=0.5) +
    geom_tile(colour = NA, width = 1, height = 0.9) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Based on your suggestion, I have found the way that I am satisfied. 

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(roi), y=time, fill = area)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  coord_fixed(ratio=2) +
  geom_tile(colour = NA, width = 1, height = 0.9) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but seems like you could just change the `height` in `geom_tile`?

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(y=factor(roi), x=time, fill = area)) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_tile(colour = "white", width = 0.9, height = 1.3) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Weihuang Wong, but I want to keep the height in 0.5 or less than. Thanks anyway your reply.